# Activity lifecycle example

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, oncreate, ondestroy

I've read numerous tutorials and seen a bunch of examples, but i'm having a hard time understand activity lifecycles. I understand what happens, my problem is I can't seem to figure out exactly how it should be coded. For example, let's say I have an simple app that added two numbers once a button was pressed. I know what to code for the onCreate method, but i'm stumped as to what to add the the onPause,onRestart etc. Would I just remove the contents of variables? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It totally depends on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I had created one example to help you understand the life cycle of an Activity. On the first time that you launch your screen, the following three life cycle methods get called:

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

Whenever we press back button while the app is running then the following life cycle methods get called:

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

When we press the home button while the app is running, the following life cycle methods get called:

```
onPause()
onStop()
```

And when we resume the app after pressing the home button, the following life cycle methods get called:

```
onRestart()
onStart()
onResume()
```

I think this will help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onCreate():","Activity is created");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onStart():","Activity started");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is Restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onRestart():","Activity Restarted");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is Resumed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onResume():","Activity Resumed");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onPause():","Activity paused");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onStop():","Activity stopped");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Activity is Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("onDestroy():","Activity destroyed");
}

}
```

Comment: An activity is never destroyed untiadb shell

Comment: When an activity is running and if you press back button then onDestroy() method of that activity get called.

Answer (score 0):

On a single app like u suggest you dont need to override any of that methods ... unless you want to make an important action before/after any activity transition or when app closes/open/go background, like stopping a service, start a session or even Logging the activity states while app is running.

Its important you to understand all the activity life-cycle callbacks and how you can use it to optimize your app.

**For example:** you are navigating on an app where use your smartphone camera, and suddenly you receive a call from your friend. automatically the app calls `onPause()` method, and (lets suppose) inside you have something like `myCamera.release()` which force the camera to stop working in background.

**Why do you need to do that?** to optimize battery and memory usage. you dont know if the app will be killed and force it to close ... so its a good practice to implement that.

you have this examples and explanations on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

Hope to be helpful.

Comment: It is definitely helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

this code from coursera lab check it

```
 package course.labs.activitylab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

    // Use these as keys when you're saving state between reconfigurations
    private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
    private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
    private static final String START_KEY = "start";
    private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

    // String for LogCat documentation
    private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityOne";

    // Lifecycle counters

    // TODO:
    // Create variables named
    // mCreate, mRestart, mStart and mResume
    // to count calls to onCreate(), onRestart(), onStart() and
    // onResume(). These variables should not be defined as static.
    int mCreate = 0 , mRestart=0 , mStart = 0 , mResume = 0;

    // You will need to increment these variables' values when their
    // corresponding lifecycle methods get called.

    // TODO: Create variables for each of the TextViews
    // named mTvCreate, mTvRestart, mTvStart, mTvResume.
    // for displaying the current count of each counter variable

    TextView mTvCreate , mTvRestart , mTvStart , mTvResume ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        // TODO: Assign the appropriate TextViews to the TextView variables
        // Hint: Access the TextView by calling Activity's findViewById()
        // textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
        mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restart);
        mTvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
        mTvResume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resume);


        Button launchActivityTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchActivityTwo);
        launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO:
                // Launch Activity Two
                // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method

                // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to
                // start
                startActivity(new Intent (ActivityOne.this , ActivityTwo.class));

                // Launch the Activity using the intent

            }
        });

        // Has previous state been saved?
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            // TODO:
            // Restore value of counters from saved state
            // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable

            mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
            mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
            mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
            mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);

        }

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onCreate() method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface via the displayCounts() method
        mCreate ++;
        displayCounts();

    }

    // Lifecycle callback overrides

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStart() method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
        mStart++;
        displayCounts();


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onResume() method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
        mResume ++;
        displayCounts();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onPause() method");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStop() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onRestart() method");

        // TODO:
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
        mRestart ++;
        displayCounts();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onDestroy() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO:
        // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs
        // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);



    }

    // Updates the displayed counters
    // This method expects that the counters and TextView variables use the
    // names
    // specified above
    public void displayCounts() {

        // TODO - uncomment these lines

        mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
        mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);
        mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);
        mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);

    }
}
```